# After I installed the setup.exe which is packed up by installshield 2013, nothing happened when running the program

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, installshield

I came here just to find a solution to debug such kind of problem but no satisfying answer yet.

The original content as below:
The program I wrote in c# and WPF in VS 2013 is packaged by Installshield LE 2013, and there is no error during the package procedure. Then I ran the Setup.exe to install the program and there's nothing wrong either. However, after I run the program installed, nothing happened, neither error message reports nor visible windows, even I didn't find any process concerned in the task manager.

I can't figure out where the problem is, for there's no error or clue to analyze and investigate. Maybe something I missed when adding application files, I guess.

By the way, I used Sqlite as database and packaged the data file under the bin directory, is it one of the reasons?

Comment: Please do your analysis before posting question in SO

Comment: Previously, I didn't find a proper way to debug such problem so I didn't find a clue to infer or analyze. So I finally came to SO to search for some guidance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'analysis'. I had given the inference and in the end, it did have something with missing import files. What analysis do you think I should do in addition to that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used install shield but setup project can be an alternative solution to your problem.
Here is a link that explains step by step procedure of creating a setup project and .msi file afterwards. Have a look.

http://www.c-/UploadFile/dpatra/create-setup-and-deployment-of-wpf-application-step-by-step/

Comment: Thx for your answer anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
It's not about InstallShield. It's about dependencies. There're two .dll files I didn't packaged, which resulted in the errors in running this program.

So I do the debugging by removing the files under Debug directory to judge which file is necessary to run this program. Maybe it's not a good way to solve such problem but for me, it worked after all.